# What is the probability that outcome A occurs N times before outcome B occurs M times?

Tags: probability

When rolling two six-sided dice and adding their results together, there are 11 possible outcomes (2 through 12). Each outcome has a different probability of occurring, with 7 being the most likely and 2 and 12 being the least likely.

For each outcome, I choose a set number of occurrences required for that outcome to "win," which I call the "target" for that outcome. I roll the dice, note the outcome, and check if any of the outcomes has "won." Then I repeat until there is a winner. I want to know the chance each outcome has to win the "race."

I know that if I set the targets as follows:

| Outcome | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Target | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |

then each outcome has an equal chance of winning. If I look at outcome 6 vs. outcome 7 for example, I can see that outcome 6 has $\frac{5}{6} \approx 83.33\%$ as many occurrences needed, but it also has a $\frac{5}{6} \approx 83.33\%$ chance of occurring.

If I then set the target for outcome 7 to be only 5 occurrences needed, I can tell that outcomes 6 and 7 need an equal amount of occurrences to win, but outcome 6 is still $\frac{5}{6} \approx 83.33\%$ as likely to be rolled.

**The part I am stuck on is figuring out how to compute the probability that a given outcome wins this race.**

If we simplify the problem to an unfair coin, say $70\%$ head and $30\%$ tails, it's intuitive that heads and tails would win with equal probability if heads had a target of 7 and tails had a target of 3. But I can't come up with a way to compute the actual probability values that heads or tails would get to their target first when the targets are not fairly distributed.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: 1. You should provide one concrete example instead of dwelling in vague generalities. 2. This forum also expects that you should  tell what you have tried and where you are stuck, for appropriate help to be given.

Comment: The easy approach to problems of this nature, when there are two (and only two) outcomes, and you want to know whether A occurs $M$ times before B occurs $N$ times is to apply the binomial theorem, to $(M+N-1)$ outcomes.  This number of outcomes guarantees exactly one winner, among A and B.  See [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), 
specifically $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{(n-k)}.$

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I will make an edit.

Comment: Simulation is often good enough for this kind of problem. With the target set as in shown in the chart, $2$ and $12$ are the most likely winners at about $24.1\%$ each.

Comment: @DanielMathias I didn't believe that, but then I simulated it myself and got the same result. Then I thought harder about it and it makes more sense to me now. Because the order of the trials matters (the race is cut short when one outcome wins), the assumption I made about the numbers being "fair" was not quite right. So that's a step in the right direction for my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ and $q$ be the probabilities of outcomes $A$ and $B$ respectively.

**Special case where $p+q=1$.** In this case there are no other outcomes besides $A$ and $B$. As user2661923 alludes to in the comments, the event "$A$ occurs $N$ times before $B$ occurs $M$ times" is equivalent to "$A$ occurs at least $N$ times in the first $N+M-1$ trials." (Check for yourself that you can reason why this is true.) By the binomial distribution, this event has probability $\sum_{k=N}^{N+M-1} \binom{N+M-1}{k} p^k q^{N+M-1-k}$.

**General case where $p+q < 1$.** We simply discard any outcomes that aren't $A$ nor $B$. The conditional probabilities of $A$ and $B$ occurring for an outcome given that the outcome is not discarded then becomes $p' := \frac{p}{p+q}$ and $q' := \frac{q}{p+q}$. The probability is then the same as the above special case, but with $p'$ and $q'$ replacing $p$ and $q$ respectively.

Comment: I don't exactly follow the general case part. If $p = \frac{1}{3}$ and $q = \frac{1}{3}$, then $p' = 1$ and $q' = 1$, which means it can't be equivalent to the special case because $p' + q' = 2$.

Comment: @nullromo Sorry, fixed the expressions for $p'$ and $q'$.

Comment: Ah, ok I see what you mean. The new probability of the event in question is the chance of that event divided by the sum of the chances of the other non-discarded events. Thanks; I will try to apply this to my specific problem.